# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys' (Python)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

I'm writing a function that takes a number of dictionaries (keys - letters, values - numbers) and combines them into one dictionary. Dict values should be summarized in case of identical keys, but alwayw recieve the error for the line with "   if k in d.keys():"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

```
def combine(*args):
    d = args[0]

    for dct in args[1:]:
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if k in d.keys():
                d[k] = d[k] + v
        d = d.update(dct)
    print(d)


dict_1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
dict_2 = {'a': 200, 'c': 300}
dict_3 = {'a': 300, 'd': 100}

combine_dicts(dict_1, dict_2, dict_3)
```

result should be {'a': 600, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 100}

Comment: Your error stems from the call to `update()`. That method returns `None`. You meant to write: `d.update(dct)`. (However, note that even then you don't get your expected result)

Comment: Do you need to update the first argument in-place, or can you start with an *empty* dict and treat `args[0]` the same way you treat the rest of the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code.
 1. `d = d.update(dct)` will override exist data and and that's where you are getting `AttributeError:` because a none is returned. 2. You are calling a wrong function, your function is called `combine` and you are calling `combine_dicts`.

This is one of the appropriate approaches you can take you can taking using `defaultdict` from collections.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def combine(*args):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for dct in args:
        for key, value in dct.items():
            d[key] += value
    print(dict(d))

dict_1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
dict_2 = {'a': 200, 'c': 300}
dict_3 = {'a': 300, 'd': 100}

combine(dict_1, dict_2, dict_3)
```

---

```
{'a': 600, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer)
since dictionaries are mutable are should've used
d.update() instead of d = d.update(). And one else mistake, but not according to the question topic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to accumulate values from the other two dicts into the first one, or just transfer values if not already present.

This is the code you want:

```py
def combine(*args):
    d = args[0]
    for dct in args[1:]:
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if k in d.keys():
                d[k] = d[k] + v
            else:
                d[k] = v
        
    print(d)


dict_1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
dict_2 = {'a': 200, 'c': 300}
dict_3 = {'a': 300, 'd': 100}

combine(dict_1, dict_2, dict_3)
```

Output as requested